# Apache webserver on Windows 7 to closed network

Tags: windows-7, networking, apache-http-server, hosts-file

I am trying to serve an Apache webserver, installed on my Windows 7 computer, to everyone on our closed network. The websites run fine when I test them locally, using `http://localhost/`, but when I try to access them from another computer on the network, using the computer name or the IP address, I just get timeouts.

I have always been able to do this before. What am I doing wrong!?

We are on a Windows domain, if that affects anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Windows firewall to see if it's blocking inbound connections on port 80. Try temporarily turning Windows (and any other) firewall off and testing from another machine.

You also need to configure the Apache "Listen" directive to `Listen 80` so that it listens to port 80 on all interfaces. See https://serverfault.com/questions/511018/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-on-multiple-network-interfaces

You need to find the `httpd.conf` file (in your Apache folder will be `httpd.conf` somewhere - probably in the `conf` folder`).

Reconfigure Apache and then restart the service.

You can then point any of your hosts to the IP address of your web server and it'll load the site.

If you're running a CMS such as WordPress then you need to configure the WordPress install to have the site name and site URL to be the IP - unless you use name-based virtual hosts - where you can create your own "in-house" domain name. You can then do all sorts of nice things like using a real domain name in the browser and your site will open as if you're using the Internet (Note: this requires additional configuration).

Comment: Apache is already listening on port 80. Any other clues?

Comment: Does your `Listen` literally just say `Listen 80` ??? try it with `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`  to rule out syntax error as it's a Windows box... Shouldn't make a difference but you never know with Windows.

Comment: 0.0.0.0:80 doesn't work either. I've also tried 127.0.0.1:80. Is it something our server could interfere with? Because I can navigate to the Exchange server and get the generic IIS splash page.

Comment: Don't use 127.0.0.1 because it'll tell Apache to only listen on localhost and will never work. Try disabling Windows (or any other installed) firewall

Comment: FIREWALL! Now I remember! Thanks a lot! Add it as answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Already done it ;)